# Promise not working properly in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Promise is not working properly **saveService** is called before promise resolved means all documents get uploaded, but when I log the data in the **saveService** it shows the uploaded docs unable to figure out the issue, please let me know where i am wrong

```
//file upload
$scope.fileObj = {};
$scope.documentUploaded = [];
var uploadFile = function (type) {

    var file = $scope.fileObj[type];

    //service to upload file
    fileService.uploadDocument(file)
        .success(function (data, status) {

            console.log("uploaded successfully", data);

            $scope.documentUploaded.push({
                doc: {
                    fileName: data.name,
                    path: data.path
                }
            });

        })
        .error(function (data, status) {

        });          
}


$scope.save = function () { //on click of submit, save() is called

var defer = $q.defer();
var promises = [];        

//looping to upload files       
angular.forEach($scope.documentList, function (doc) {

    if ($scope.fileObj[doc.type]) {
       promises.push(uploadFile(doc.type));                
    }            
});

//this will save data when promise will get complete
var saveData = function () {
    var dataToSave = {
        //other fields
        documents: $scope.documentUploaded
    };

    saveService.saveApi(dataToSave)
        .success(function () {
            defer.resolve('data saved');                    
        })
        .error(function () {
            defer.reject("something went wrong");                    
        });
}

$q.all(promises).then(saveData);
return defer;
```

}

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close this question.   With this line of code `$q.all(promises).then(saveData);`, the OP is expecting that all the `uploadFile()` operations will complete before `saveData()` is called, but that is not happening and they want to know why.

Answer (score 4):

`uploadFile()` needs to return a promise (that is resolved when its work is done) for `$q.all(promises)` to work.

Right now it isn't returning anything so you're passing `$q.all()` an array of undefined values.  Since there are no promises in that array, `$q.all()` executes the `.then()` handler immediately.

Here's a condensed version of the problem:

```
var promises = [];
...forEach(function() {
    promises.push(uploadFile(doc.type)); 
});
$q.all(promises).then(saveData);
```

So, you're pushing into the promises array the return value from `uploadFile()`.  But `uploadFile()` doesn't even return anything.  So, you're pushing in `undefined`.  Then, you pass an array of `undefined` values to `$q.all` when it's expecting an array of promises.

So, to make this logic work, you need `uploadFile()` to return a promise that gets resolved when that instance of `uploadfile()` is done with its async work.

---

If `fileService.uploadDocument()` already returns a promise, you can just return that promise.  If not, then you can create one at the beginning of `uploadFile()` and return it at the end and then resolve or reject it in the `.success()` and `.error()` handlers.

---

If `fileService.uploadDocument()` can already make a promise, then the preferred solution would be to use that promise (I don't know that API so don't know how it works).  If it can't make a promise, then you can make your own like this:

```
var uploadFile = function (type) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var file = $scope.fileObj[type];

    //service to upload file
    fileService.uploadDocument(file)
        .success(function (data, status) {
            console.log("uploaded successfully", data);
            $scope.documentUploaded.push({
                doc: {
                    fileName: data.name,
                    path: data.path
                }
            });
            defer.resolve();

        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            defer.reject();
        });          
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: I am new to promises can you please tell me how to do that. i am just doing http in the service

Comment: @AshutoshVerma - where does `fileService.uploadDocument()` come from?  Can you point me to some documentation for that because I want to know if it already can make a promise for you.

Comment: @AshutoshVerma - I added a solution where `uploadFile()` makes and resolves its own promise.